# reactjs : i am trying to make a small scollbar

Tags: css, reactjs

i am trying to make a small scollbar in react js  in css it works only when given like this  scrollbar-width: thin;  but react does not supported "-" so i used like below but its not working the scroll bar is appearing i cant use inline or class styling

```
const styles = {

  module: {
    height: "30rem",
    overflowY: "scroll",
    scrollbarWidth: "thin",  // this doesnot work
  },
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this way: push CSS code to another file then import that to react page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).